# uWSGI and Python - KeyboardInterrupt cycles

Tags: python, uwsgi

I've setup a python3.9 django project with uWSGI 2.0.12. It seems that every few seconds or so the service crashes and restarts due to some bug in python related to the random seed and a `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here? In general the app works, but every so often its not responsive.

The following log lines repeat themselves over and over again.

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18 (64bit) on [Sat Jul 30 00:25:13 2022] ***
compiled with version: 11.2.1 20210728 (Red Hat 11.2.1-2) on 27 January 2021 00:00:00
os: Linux-5.14.0-80.el9.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Apr 21 09:50:22 UTC 2022
nodename: abc.dev
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 2
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi.d
detected binary path: /usr/sbin/uwsgi
chdir() to /opt/abc-api/mysite
your processes number limit is 15518
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /var/sockets/api.abc.dev.sock fd 6
Python version: 3.9.13 (main, Jun  9 2022, 00:00:00)  [GCC 11.3.1 20220421 (Red Hat 11.3.1-2)]
PEP 405 virtualenv detected: /opt/abc-api/venv
Set PythonHome to /opt/abc-api/venv
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0xb32450
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 145840 bytes (142 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0xb32450 pid: 219059 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 219059)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 219060, cores: 1)
Sat Jul 30 00:25:13 2022 - received message 0 from emperor
SIGINT/SIGQUIT received...killing workers...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/random.py", line 126, in seed
    def seed(self, a=None, version=2):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Update:
I've tried many things - including going back python3.7 (couldn't get it to work, different issue...). Finally I went back to 3.9 setup, but instead of using a socket file, I decided on http socket at 127.0.0.1:8181. Now this issue is not happening. Zero clue what's going on, but looks like it has to do with the socket file.

Comment: Any chance you had either Brotli or Whitenoise libraries as dependencies?